# how to remove an item from a list if the list is greater than 1?

Tags: python

i have a list, and I want the list to only be one item long, how to do this? I have tried doing this, but it gave me an error: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Here's the code:

```
List = ["dairy"]
List.append("cheese")

if len(List) > 1:
    List.remove(1)
```

Comment: What did you expect from `List > 1`? If you mean the *length* you need to be explicit, `len(List) > 1`.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? You "want the list to only be one item long", yet you accepted an answer that does something different: removing one item from the list. What you asked in your question is only achieved if the starting list has exactly 1 or 2 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's .remove() method takes the value you want to remove as its argument, so it is looking for the number 1 in the list. To remove by index, you can use del or .pop(). Eg:

```
l  = ['dairy']
l.append('cheese')

if len(l) > 1:
     l.pop() # Removes last item in list
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer was accepted (OTOH the OP accepted a bad answer on the topic of floating points too). The question stated "I want the list to only be one item long". Now if you run this solution with any list with more than 2 elements the answer is just wrong. Solution for that: `if l: l[:] = l[0]`

Comment: He accepted it because I directly answered his question regarding why he got an error, and provided a solution to that error. However your point is fair, and probably a more robust solution, but as OP presented the problem this I understood him to mean that the list would be 1 item long, a second item may or may not be added, and then the check is performed each time. If that's not the case then my solution would not be appropriate, but also OP's original code would be incorrect in that sense, but that was not the subject of the question.